# Descriptografar MD5

Tags: c#, criptografia, md5

Necessito alterar este código para descriptografar os dados com ele criptografados:

```
public static string MD5HashCrypt(string text)
{
    MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

    //compute hash from the bytes of text
    md5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text));

    //get hash result after compute it
    byte[] result = md5.Hash;

    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
    {
        //change it into 2 hexadecimal digits
        //for each byte
        strBuilder.Append(result[i].ToString("x2"));
    }

    return strBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: MD5 é uma hash (bem insegura, alias). Você não conseguirá reverter. A única forma de "reverter" seria fazendo uma busca exaustiva até achar um outro valor com a mesma hash, mais isso não garante que você achou o valor original. Enfim, se você quer obter o texto original num momento futuro, você precisa usar encriptação e não resumos. Você pode usar AES-CGM ou ChaCha20Poly1305, por exemplo. Dessa forma apenas quem detêm uma chave criptográfica pode ler os dados.

Comment: Hash por si não descriptografa, existe formas de quebrar como o @Inkeliz disse, mas por padrão é isso aí. Por isso alguns sites quando você perde a senha e eles usam hash você recebe um senha nova no email, quando o site te envia a sua senha atual no email pode ter certeza que a segurança deles é um lixo ! :)

Comment: @Inkeliz por que insegura? Poderia me explicar?

Comment: @CypherPotato é extremamente fácil colidir, isso já era possível desde 1994, com uma [maquina que custava ~10 milhões de dólares e demora apenas 21 dias](https://goo.gl/QHJVLz). Já conseguiram [forjar assinaturas de SSL usando 200 playstation 3](https://goo.gl/dnbvLX), o SHA-1 está no mesmo patamar, inclusive certificados [SSL usando SHA-1 não são mais confiáveis](https://goo.gl/2bcG7t). A NSA já recomenda que use 384 bits, já a ECRYPT II recomenda que use hashes de 512 bits, se quiser sobreviver além de 2040. Nem sequer paddings que usem SHA-1 devem ser considerados seguros.

Answer (score 1):

MD5 é um **algoritmo de hashing**, e não de criptografia. **É expressamente impossível reverter a ação do Hash**.

O **Hash** é usado dentro de um sistema de criptografia, mais precisamente usado para encriptar senhas, tornando-as pseudoaleatórias, assim, impossibilitando um meio de obter a senha através do Hash.

Por suma, não é possível decriptografar um MD5.